# Trying to modify a list in Python

Tags: python

I'm reading the *Python Crash Course* book by Eric Matthes, and I'm working on this exercise:

> 8-9. Magicians: Make a list of magician’s names . Pass the list to a
>   function called `show_magicians()`, which prints the name of each
>   magician in the list .
>
> 8-10. Great Magicians: Start with a copy of
>   your program from Exercise 8-9 . Write a function called `make_great()`
>   that modifies the list of magicians by add- ing the phrase the Great
>   to each magician’s name . Call `show_magicians()` to see that the list
>   has actually been modified .

In his book he modifies lists by passing them as arguments in a function, and that function changes the list, but all I get is a list of the original names.
What did I do wrong?

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician.title())


def make_great(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        magician = "Great " + magician



magicians = ['hermione','mihai','harry potter', 'voldemort']

make_great(magicians)
show_magicians(magicians)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `make_great` function does nothing to the list.

```
def make_great(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        magician = "Great " + magician
```

It has one local variable that you change several times, but you never change the list.  Instead:

```
def make_great(magicians):
    for i in range(len(magicians)):
        magicians[i] = "Great " + magicians[i]
```

Output:

```
Great Hermione
Great Mihai
Great Harry Potter
Great Voldemort
```

Comment: Thank you for your explications.

Comment: `for i, magician in enumerate(magicians):` would be a slightly more pythonic way to do the loop, though the result is the same ultimately

Comment: @DanielR. Unless you change the code to use `magician` in the renaming, the `enumerate` doesn't flow well.

Comment: Yeah it should be `for i,magician in enumerate(magicians):` and `magicians[i] = "Great " + magician`

Answer (score 4):

You can't reassign an element into the list like that. When you reassign `magician` in the loop, all that's doing is reassigning the local variable that *used* to refer to a String in `magicians`.

Use a comprehension to create a new list that has "Great" prepended to each string; which you return:

```
def make_great(magicians):
  return ["Great " + magician for magician in magicians] 

magicians = ['hermione','mihai','harry potter', 'voldemort']

# Returned a new list to use
great_magicians = make_great(magicians)
print(great_magicians) # ['Great hermione', 'Great mihai', 'Great harry potter', 'Great voldemort']
```

You *can* alter lists passed in to functions:

```
def f(my_list):
  my_list[0] = 2

l = [1, 2, 3]
f(l)
print(l) # [2, 2, 3]
```

And you *can* mutate the objects in the list while iterating:

```
def f(my_list):
  for l in my_list:
    l.append(9)

l = [[], []]
f(l)
print(l) # [[9], [9]]
```

You just can't do this with immutable objects like Strings, since immutable objects can't themselves be altered in any way.

Comment: This isn't exactly true. You can modify variables in a list like that, just not strings because they're immutable, so when you reassign them, a new object is created. If you had a list of lists and tried to append something to each list using the syntax in the original post, it would update the variables in the list.

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell Yes, you can mutate them, you just can't reassign them into the list. I'll fix my wording.

Answer (score 0):

As answered, your function did not modify orIn Python 3.6+, you could simplify the function using f-formatting

```
magicians = ['hermione','mihai','harry potter', 'voldemort']

def make_great(magicians):
    return [f'Great {i.title()}' for i in magicians]


print(make_great(magicians))
```